# Laravel send Json to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, laravel

I just start using Laravel 5 and i'm facing a problem to send Ajax json data from the view to controller ..

This is my routes.php :

```
Route::post('ticket','TicketController@store');

 Route::get('ticket', 'TicketController@index');
```

and this is the controller :

```
public function store()
{

  return Response::json(Input::get('ticketname'));

}
```

and Finally for the View i have this simple example to pass  just one input :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#go').on("click",function(){


        var ticketname=  ($('.tick_name').val());

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ticket',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {ticketname:$('.tick_name').val()},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(info){
                        console.log(info);
                    }

                });


    });

});
```

**IM ALWAYS GETTING THIS ERROR : localhost:8000/ticket

500 Internal Server Error on jquery.js line 4 ..**

CAN anyone help please !

Comment: Take a look at the error log in `storage/logs`

Comment: ok it says : "exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Response' not found' in C:/.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Response` is an alias in the *global namespace*. Since you're current namespace is `App\Http\Controllers` you have to import the class:

```
use Response;
```

Or prepend a backslash:

```
return \Response::json(Input::get('ticketname'));
```

Comment: Thanks , but now i've got this error "exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input' not found' i have added use Symfony\Component\Console\Input; but still not working

Comment: Just add `use Input;`

Comment: OMG , Thanks a lot :/ im a noob on Laravel